# How should you scale objects in a miniature world?

Tags: unity, blender, 3d-modeling

I'm extremely new to game dev, so I hope this question isn't too subjective, but when you're making a game with a miniature scale, what is the "right" way to deal with object sizes? Think "Army Men," "Micro Machines," "Honey We Shrunk the Kids," etc.

I have read that keeping things as close to real world scale is best because it makes modeling easier when multiple objects are placed near each other. In this case, though, I wonder if the added headache of changing grid scales in Blender, then camera scaling in Unity, etc. might make more sense to just make 1 inch real-world = 1 meter in Blender and just go from there?

Any opinions are appreciated.

Comment: camera scaling? you don't need to change anything about the camera I don't think. take any car model, and put it next to a coke can 5 times its size. it's either a giant coke can or a miniature car, how the player perceives it depends on the storytelling of the environment. surround the small car with lots of normal-sized everyday objects and it'll appear to be miniaturized. you can change the scale of objects after they've been modeled, even after they've been imported in unity.

Comment: take a look at a screenshot of Micromachines world series - they look miniaturized because they're surrounded by large everyday objects. then take a look at a screenshot of the game Mashed. the cars look toy-like, but not necessarily miniaturized because the rest of the environment does not suggest it.